# How to combine two selected columns into a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select two columns from two table and then combine them to one single table, there are no correlated column in these two tables. How can I do this?

For example:

Table A:

```
NAME TAG
A     xx
B     xx
C     xx
```

Table B:

```
NAME TAG
D     yy
E     yy
F     yy
```

I want to have an output table like below

```
xx yy
A  D
B  E
C  F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just want a vertical list.  If so, you can add an enumeration column and group by that:

```
select min(a_name), min(b_name)
from ((select row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum, name as a_name, null as b_name
       from a
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum, null, name
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Is there any command could do like (select NAME from A) combine (select NAME from B) directly that not as complicate as above?

Comment: @yixizhou . . . No there is not.  If there were, do you think I would not have that in the answer?

Comment: OK. Fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT could be the option here.